# PV on LVM-cached LV failed

Tags: linux, lvm

I created an LVM-cached LV:

```
# lvcreate local --name BigCached -L32T /dev/sda3
# lvcreate -n LVcache -L500G local /dev/sdb
# lvcreate -n LVcacheMeta -L1G local /dev/sdb
# lvconvert --type cache --cachepool local/LVcache local/BigCached
# lvs
  LV        VG    Attr       LSize   Pool    Origin            Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  BigCached local Cwi-a-C---  32,00t LVcache [BigCached_corig]
  LVcache   local Cwi---C--- 500,00g
  root      local -wi-ao----  30,00g
```

All well and good, I created an ext4 filesystem on `BigCached` and ran some benchmarks, which were satisfactory, and then unmounted it.

After that, I tried to create a PV on top of the cached volume:

```
# pvcreate /dev/local/BigCached
Physical volume "/dev/local/BigCached" successfully created
# pvs
  Found duplicate PV t3eDn0GGYTfOxRhnwnzF0C1DHWjiEg4l: using /dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig not /dev/local/BigCached
  PV                                VG    Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig       lvm2 ---   32,00t  32,00t
  /dev/sda3                         local lvm2 a--   32,74t 729,76g
  /dev/sdb                          local lvm2 a--  744,62g 243,62g
```

Ooops :(
Somehow, the non-cached original was used instead of the cached one as PV.

Ok, lets remove the PV and try again with some other parameters:

```
# pvremove /dev/local/BigCached
  Found duplicate PV t3eDn0GGYTfOxRhnwnzF0C1DHWjiEg4l: using /dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig not /dev/local/BigCached
  Internal error: Physical Volume /dev/local/BigCached has a label, but is neither in a VG nor orphan.
# pvremove -ff /dev/local/BigCached
  Found duplicate PV t3eDn0GGYTfOxRhnwnzF0C1DHWjiEg4l: using /dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig not /dev/local/BigCached
  Internal error: Physical Volume /dev/local/BigCached has a label, but is neither in a VG nor orphan.
```

I'm really stuck here: I cannot remove the PV but also cannot really safely use the underlying LV either. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use dmsetup directly to remove the cached volume:

```
# dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/local-BigCached
```

After that, I was able to remove the PV:

```
# pvremove /dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig
  Labels on physical volume "/dev/mapper/local-BigCached_corig" successfully wiped
```

Ok, let's see what remained of the LVs:

```
# lvs
  LV        VG    Attr       LSize   Pool    Origin            Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  BigCached local Cwi---C---  32,00t LVcache [BigCached_corig]
  LVcache   local Cwi---C--- 500,00g
  root      local -wi-ao----  30,00g
```

Wow, it is still there, albeit inactively...

However, when I tried to activate them, `BigCached` failed, so I was forced to remove it. I am back to square one, so I tried a different approach: use dm-cache directly instead of with lvmcache.

However, it yielded almost the same result:

```
Found duplicate PV rkVmi4Pm5ijJXYM50cz6pI5ZhMeljpic: using /dev/mapper/big-cached not /dev/local/big
```

While it is currently using the right device (/dev/mapper/big-cached), I cannot be sure this will always be the case, so this is still not a good solution.

Then I found that this case is similar to having a multipath device, and thus necessitates a [similar solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181198/found-duplicate-pv), namely an lvm filter in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf:

```
      filter = [ "r|/dev/local/big|" ]
```

Comment: If using lvmetad, use global_filter.